# How can I download magnet links through the command line with rtorrent on Linux?

Tags: linux, command-line, rtorrent, magnet-links

How can I download magnet links through the command line with rtorrent on Linux (Ubuntu)?

I know that I can

1. Run `rtorrent`
2. Hit  <kbd>Backspace</kbd>
3. Paste magnet link
4. Hit  <kbd>Enter</kbd>

However I want one or several command lines, not keyboard shortcuts.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I know this is pretty old but in case somebody else needs this answer:

```
rtorrent 'magnet link in quotes'
```

then this will open up rtorrent with that link.

Answer (score 3):

The `rtorrent` [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rtorrent) says it takes a 'URL|FILE' as the final option.  Presumably that's the torrent URL.  However it doesn't specify.

You *can't* do something like this:

```
echo -e "\b$URL" |rtorrent
```

because it's going to close `stdin` immediately and cause `rtorrent` to exit.

But, if `rtorrent` is running in another terminal session, try this:

```
echo -e "\b$URL" > /proc/$(pidof rtorrent)/fd/0
```

If you want to get the link straight from your clipboard, check out `xsel` or `xclip`. With `xclip` it would become

```
echo -e "\b$(xclip -o)" > /proc/$(pidof rtorrent)/fd/0
```

Comment: Thanks, `rtorrent [magnet link]` doesn't seem to work. `rtorrent [URL of torrent file` works.

Comment: Thanks, I am looking for a way to download magnet links, not torrent files or torrent file URLs, through the command line with rtorrent on Linux.

Comment: Ok good point!  Assume the `echo ... > /proc/$(pidof rtorrent)/fd/0` method did not work either then?

Answer (score 3):

**Mac Version:**
As this answer is the first result for "How can I download magnet links through the command line Mac" on Google, I am going to add the procedure for downloading torrent from the terminal on mac.

1. Open the terminal.
2. Install Brew (https://brew.sh/) `/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"`
3. Write `brew install transmission` once finished launch `brew install watch`
4. Once finished launch the daemon: `transmission-daemon`
5. Start the download with: `transmission-remote -a "url"`
6. To have a visual update write: `watch "transmission-remote -l"` (add the -n flag to specify an interval, the standard is 2 seconds)

For other uses there are several posts online such as: https://cli-ck.io/transmission-cli-user-guide/. This should work with some variations on Linux as Transmission is apparently distributed with its CLI on Ubuntu/Debian.

Comment: Thanks for sharing how to do it on macOS!

Comment: You are welcome!